# JQuery slicing an object with attributes

Tags: jquery, object

I have a script in jquery that generates me an object in `{name : value}` that looks like:

```
fracht_1_eta :""
fracht_1_ets :""
fracht_2_eta :"2013-11-21"
fracht_2_ets :""
fracht_3_eta :""
fracht_3_ets :"" 
oncarriage_pickup_pl:""
precarrige_date_pickup_pl:"2013-12-05"
```

Now I want to cut that object for example from `fracht_1_eta` to `fracht_3_ets`, idea is that I want to cut it dynamic, and I see slice uses int as parameter, is there a way to cut an object using only name of values in object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object properties have no order, so it doesn't make any sense to use a number to break an object into two (or more) objects. That would make sense for an array, but not for a non-array object.

You can loop through the (enumerable) properties of an object using a `for-in` loop, like so:

```
var yourObject = /*...whatever creates that object...*/;
var key;
for (key in yourObject) {
    // Here, the `key` variable will containg name of each property, e.g.
    // "fracht_1_eta"
}
```

...and then use whatever logic is appropriate to put properties in different objects instead.

For instance, here's an example putting all of the properties starting with "fracht" in a separate object:

```
var yourObject = /*...whatever creates that object...*/;
var fracht;
var key;
fracht = {}; // A new object for the "fracht" properties
for (key in yourObject) {
    if (key.substring(0, 6) === "fracht") {
        fracht[key] = yourObject[key];   // Copy the property
        delete yourObject[key];          // Remove it from the original object
    }
}
```